# terraform helm_release resource for official airflow helm chart

Tags: terraform, airflow, terraform-provider-helm

I was trying to deploy official helm chart for airflow using terraform helm release. But it says the chart repository not found. i put the repository url. May be the url is wrong.

```
  repository = "https://airflow.apache.org"
  chart      = "apache-airflow"
  name       = "airflow"
  version    = "1.7.0"
  namespace  = "airflow"
  values     = [file("${path.module}/values.yaml")]
}
```

Getting this error message:

```
Error: could not download chart: chart "apache-airflow" version "1.7.0" not found in https://airflow.apache.org repository
```

Comment: Have you seen this part: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html#installing-the-chart-with-argo-cd-flux-or-terraform? Can you add the `values.yaml` file to the question?

Comment: Thanks. i was using default values from this [link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-airflow/airflow) official helm chart. I saw that part. but didn't try yet. will try now.

Comment: @MarkoE the error remains the same. actually it's not being able download the chart from that repository.

Comment: The answer shows you how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. As per instructions from the artifacthub.io [1], the chart name is actually only `airflow` (and not `apache-airflow`), so the code needs to look like:

```
resource "helm_release" "airflow" {
  repository = "https://airflow.apache.org"
  chart      = "airflow"
  name       = "airflow"
  version    = "1.7.0"
  namespace  = "airflow"
  values     = [file("${path.root}/airflow-values.yaml")]
}
```

where the file `aiflow-values.yaml` is the one from their documentation used when installing with terraform [2].

---

[1] https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-airflow/airflow?modal=install

[2] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html#installing-the-chart-with-argo-cd-flux-or-terraform